# Joining two tables with special case on the right table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables: `Candidate`: {`Id`, `Name`} and `Candidate_Education`: {`Id`, `CandidateId`, `Education`, `GraduationDate`}

I want to show the candidate name and his last education , I made that query:

```
SELECT c.Name, ce.Education AS 'Last Education'
FROM Candidate c
LEFT JOIN Candidate_Education ce
    ON c.Id = (SELECT TOP 1 CandidateID FROM Candidate_Education
               ORDER BY GraduationDate DESC)
```

But the results is not correct, there are Candidates who assigned Educations they don't have relation with Candidate_Education

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More typical ways to do what you want use `ROW_NUMBER()` or `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT c.Name, ce.Education
FROM Candidate c OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 ce.*
      FROM Candidate_Education ce
      WHERE ce.CandidateID = c.CandidateID
      ORDER BY ce.GraduationDate DESC
     ) ce;
```

Your query is missing a join condition between the two tables in the `FROM` clause.  However, there are alternatives that are more appropriate for SQL Server.

Comment: What is `ce.*`? is it just `*`?

Comment: @MohamedAhmed . . . I like to qualify column names wherever they are used.  Hence `ce.*`.

Answer (score 0):

other solution

```
with OneCandidate as (
select * from (
                select ce.*, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by  ce.CandidateID order by ce.CandidateID desc) rang 
                from Candidate_Education ce
                ) tmp 
where tmp.rang=1
)
SELECT c.Name, ce.Education
FROM Candidate c left outer OneCandidate ce on ce.CandidateID = c.CandidateID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH maxGraduationCTE AS
(SELECT Id, MAX(GraduationDate) AS 'Last Education' FROM Candidate_Education 
 GROUP BY Id),

lastEducationCTE AS 
(SELECT [Last Education], ce.Id, ce.CandidateId, ce.Education FROM maxGraduationCTE
 INNER JOIN Candidate_Education ce ON maxGraduationCTE.Id = ce.Id);

SELECT c.Name, 
CASE WHEN [Last Education] IS NULL THEN 'No Education'
     ELSE CAST([Last Education] As Varchar) 
END As [Last Education]
FROM Candidate c
LEFT JOIN lastEducationCTE ce
ON c.Id = ce.CandidateId
```

You could use two CTE expressions and a left join with a CASE statement to handle null values.  I used a case because I wasn't sure about the data type for the GraduationDate...may have to convert it because if it is a date, you can't mix varchar and date data types